# how to send mail in strapi cms while submit form from frontend

Tags: content-management-system, strapi, mail-server

using strapi version4, tried this for send mail, but did not work for me.

https://strapi.io/blog/how-to-create-and-use-sms-and-email-services-in-strapi-1

could you please explain me on how to override create method in strapi cms.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Nodemailer or Sendgrid, I'm gonna use Nodemailer in this example but I personally prefer SendGrid.

ssh to your strapi server

- install nodemailer: **npm i @strapi/provider-email-nodemailer**
- choose **config folder / plugins.js** - you can create it as a new file if you dont have

Copy this:

```
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  // ...
  email: {
    config: {
      provider: 'nodemailer',
      providerOptions: {
        host: env('SMTP_HOST', 'smtp.example.com'),
        port: env('SMTP_PORT', 587),
        auth: {
          user: env('SMTP_USERNAME'),
          pass: env('SMTP_PASSWORD'),
        },
      },
      settings: {
        defaultFrom: 'your_email@address.com',
        defaultReplyTo: 'your_email@address.com',
      },
    },
  },
});
```

- inside your project there is an **.env** file, open it and copy:

  EMAIL_PROVIDER=nodemailer
  EMAIL_SMTP_HOST=sandbox.smtp.mailtrap.io
  EMAIL_SMTP_PORT=2525
  EMAIL_SMTP_USER=your_mailtrap_user
  EMAIL_SMTP_PASS=your_mailtrap_password
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_FROM=your_email@address.com
  EMAIL_ADDRESS_REPLY=your_email@address.com

Notice I'm using mailtrap here for testing purposes, you can [sign up here](https://mailtrap.io/register/signup?ref=header)

- e-mail testing
- add an inbox
- on the right side **Integrations** choose **nodemailer** and you'll see the password and user

go back to your strapi project
**src/api/choose your collection type where you store the data you sent from frontend/content-types**

in content-types make a new file called **lifecycles.js** and copy this:

```
module.exports = {
  async afterCreate(event) {
    const { result } = event;
    try {
      await strapi.plugins['email'].services.email.send({
        to: 'your_email@address.com',
        from: `your_email@address.com`,
        subject: `This is a test mail`,
        html: `Hello world ${result.name}` //<- (you'll need a name field in strapi collection type to display this data)
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  },
};
```

Now each time there is a new post from your frontend to strapi you'll receive an email to your mailtrap account, later you can use a real SMTP server instead of mailtrap.
You can also make a test in strapi admin panel **Settings/E-mail plugin - Configuration**

[plugins.js,lifecycles.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uYS99.png)
[.env](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SzWHK.png)

Hope it helps!

Comment: Hi @jeremy0505h , I have tried your method. But unfortunately it is not working with me. Here is my question with more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77429409/strapi-js-contact-us-form-can-not-get-the-email

I appreciate your help.