# Strapi js Contact us form can not get the email

Tags: javascript, node.js, sendgrid, strapi

I have a Strapi application which I set up with sendGrid. If I try to send test mail from the admin ui **Settings>Email Plugin>Configuration**, I get the email successfully in the test email address. But when I try to configure it with my contact us form, so that I get email every time there is a new entry in the contact-us-query collection, I do not get any email at all. My guess is that the emailer from the services are not getting triggered at all!

I have made some researches on stackoverflow and Bard, found out how the lifeCycles work. Created a lifecycles.js src>api>contact-us-query folder and wrote this piece of code as everyone suggested:

```
const { email } = strapi.plugins['email'].services;

async function sendContactUsEmail(event) {
  const query = event.result;

  const emailOptions = {
    to: env('RECIEVER_EMAIL'),
    from: env('SENDGRID_EMAIL'),
    subject: 'New contact us query',
    text: `You have received a new contact us query from ${query.name} (${query.email}). Their message is: ${query.message}`,
  };

  await email.send(emailOptions);
}

strapi.hooks.addHook('afterCreate', 'api::contact-us-queries', sendContactUsEmail);
```

Please take note that when I do the

> const { email } = strapi.plugins['email'].services;

the {email} function doesn't come up in the VS code auto suggestion. This can mean that the email from the services is not getting injected in the code.

I have been scratching my head the whole evening. Please let me know what I am doing wrong and what can be done here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

to get list of available services, you can use: `yarn strapi services:list`

then you can see:

```
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│ plugin::email.email                               │
├───────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
```

to get service you can then use:

```
strapi.service('plugin::email.email').send({...})
```

the intellisense not going to work in this case due to strapi has some issues with typescript...

but you can try to `console.log(strapi.service('plugin::email.email'))`

about your hooks registration, normally i do that via:

`src/index.ts`

```
{
  ...
 bootstrap({ strapi }:{strapi:Strapi}) {
    strapi.db.lifecycles.subscribe({
    // @ts-expect-error strapi-misstype
    models: ['api::what.ever'],
    afterCreate: async (event) => {
      ...
      try {
       await strapi.service('plugin::email.email').send({...})
      }
      catch {
       // error suppression if send fails
      }
    }
 },
 ...
}
```

p.s.:

Not sure if this works outside /config

```
to: env('RECIEVER_EMAIL'),
from: env('SENDGRID_EMAIL'),
```

you better double check that